# iOS 5: Upgrade iPad2 but now Xcode4 isn't happy

Tags: ios4, xcode4, ios5

I upgrade my iPad2 to iOS 5, hoping that I could continue developing with iOS 4 as my target.

So then I upgraded to Xcode 4.3 & iOS 5 SDK, but the iOS 4 target disappeared. Therefore I downgraded back to iOS 3 then upgraded again to 4.1.

Presently I get this message:

```
The version of iOS on “iPad” does not match 
any of the versions of iOS supported for development 
with this installation of the iOS SDK.
```

Is there a way to set up Xcode to compile for both iOS 4 and iOS 5, if I wish?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the solution is to use two different installs of Xcode, one for each target SDK. Have you tried using the iOS 5 SDK but setting the "Deployment Target" to iOS 4?

Comment: Thanks, as a matter of fact, that's what I'm doing right now. Xcode3 will remain in /Developer & Xcode4 is installing into /Xcode4.

Comment: Thats is exactly how I solved the problem for me as well. Had the same one, except for xCode latest official and latest beta. Works great for me now.